# HTML canvas not drawing image from file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to load an image from a file and draw it on a canvas. I have this..

```
const canvas  = document.createElement("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "img/image.jpg";

context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

This is not drawing anything on the screen, where am I going wrong? I can see the image being loaded by developer tools so I know that it can find the file itself.

Comment: Have you checked the myImage.onload event?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console and I was not aware of the onload event. Will read up on that now

Comment: Are you appending the canvas element to the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

If the `canvas` element is already on the page, you'll need to replace the `createElement` method with `querySelector`:

```js
// const canvas  = document.createElement("canvas");
const canvas  = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "img/image.jpg";

myImage.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}); // Thanks to Xion 14 for the reminder!
```

Otherwise, you'll need to append the canvas element to the DOM, e.g. via `document.body.appendChild( canvas );`

Comment: You need also to wait for the image to load before drawing it in the canvas.

Comment: This is not working for me, I get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:.addEventlistener is not a function

Comment: @fightstarr20 Sorry, there was a typo. It's camelCase: addEventListener